# Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors 'none' not working

Tags: node.js, iframe, content-security-policy, clickjacking

I'm trying to disable all iframes from my website by setting it in the `Content-Security-Policy` headers of my response in the Node layer. According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors), the property should look like this from the perspective of the client-side:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
```

That's fine, here's how I'm setting it in the Node layer in my middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    /* Clickjacking prevention */
    res.header('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'none'")
    next()
})
```

and here's how it appears in the client-side when I inspect network activity:

[image]

However, when I embed a YouTube iframe, such as the following:

```
<iframe
 width="420"
 height="345"
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"/>
```

it's not disabled. Why does the frame-ancestors policy appear to have no effect? Testing this on Chrome for what it's worth.

Comment: The frame-ancestors directive prevents other documents from framing/embedding your document; it doesn’t prevent your document from framing/embedding other documents (such at the youtube-embedding iframe in the question).

Comment: i think there is a bug on chrome, also in firefox, and chrome etc...i think this directive does not have any support...https://csplite.com/csp/test355/#bug_Chrome_path_frame-ancestors

Answer (score 4):

`frame-ancestors` specify which pages can **frame the current page**.

If you want to limit the **iframes that can be on the current page** you can use [`child-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src).

However, the `child-src` directive also applies to web workers. You can override it using the `worker-src` directive

Comment: What i understand from docs, is the same as question. I have same problem.  It should not allow using "iframe" tag in html document normally. (for ; frame-ancestors 'none')

Comment: i think there is a bug on chrome, also in firefox, and chrome etc...i think this directive does not have any support...csplite.com/csp/test355/#bug_Chrome_path_frame-ancestors